# Does setting a mysql attribute in php change the attribute for everyone or just the current connection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm running a mysql query in php that returns a lot of data and takes some time to run. In order for this query to run I have to tell mysql to not buffer the query.

I'm using a mysql cursor to process the query as its being executed which allows me to greatly save on memory usage.

In order to use the cursor I have to set `MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY = false`.

For example:

```
// Turn off mysql buffering
DB::connection()->getPdo()->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

$complexQuery->cursor();

// Turn mysql buffering back on
DB::connection()->getPdo()->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
```

This query takes around 12 seconds to run.  I want to know if during this time other sessions also have `MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY = false` or is it connection specific?

Comment: It only affects your connection and only until your program ends.